# prolog - continue recursion if false

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am writing this piece of code:

```
score_one_topic(_,[],0).
score_one_topic(Topic,[H|T],Score):-
   pairs_keys_values([H],[X],_),
   sub_string(case_insensitive,X,Topic),
   get_weight(H,Weight),
   Score is Weight + ScoreTemp.
```

So, basically I have a list of keywords and each keyword has a weight.

With score_one_topic I compute the score of the Topic (for example Topic = 'Nice Weather'). The score is initially 0 and everytime a keyword from the list is a sub_string of the Topic the score is being incremented by the weight of the keyword.

My problem is that if a keyword from the list is not a substring of the topic it returns false and the Score is lost..is there any way to continue the recursion even though sub_string returns false?

Comment: I don't see a recursive call in your predicate. Is this your latest code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the recursion in your posted code. I assume it looks something like this:

```
score_one_topic(Topic, [H|T], Score):-
   pairs_keys_values([H], [X], _),
   sub_string(case_insensitive, X, Topic),
   get_weight(H, Weight),
   score_one_topic(Topic, T, ScoreTemp),
   Score is Weight + ScoreTemp.
```

One way to get the result you want is to make scoring succeed on a mismatched substring, but yield a 0 score:

```
score_one_topic(Topic, [H|T], Score):-
   sub_string_score(Topic, H, SubScore),
   score_one_topic(Topic, T, RestScore),
   Score is RestScore + SubScore.

sub_string_score(Topic, X, SubScore) :-
   pairs_keys_values([H], [X], _),
   sub_string(case_insensitive, X, Topic), !,
   get_weight(H, SubScore).
sub_string_score(_, _, 0).
```

Now that you have a predicate that computes the score for one list item, you can use `maplist`:

```
score_one_topic(Topic, Keys, Score) :-
    maplist(sub_string_score(Topic), Keys, Scores),
    sum_list(Scores, Score).
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, so the final code that worked for me is :

```
score_one_topic(_,[],0).

score_one_topic(Topic, [H|T], Score):-
    score_one_topic(Topic, T, RestScore),
    sub_string_score(Topic, H, SubScore),
    Score is RestScore + SubScore.

sub_string_score(Topic, H, SubScore) :-
    pairs_keys_values([H], [X], _),
    sub_string(case_insensitive, X, Topic), !,
    get_weight(H, SubScore).

sub_string_score(_, _, 0).
```

For example  :

```
?- score_one_topic('Programming is fun',[programming-2,prolog-5,fun-2],Score). 

Score=4
```